# Auth token from dialog to bot class

Tags: c#, oauth, botframework

I am running an OAuth Dialog that allows user to sign in. I am looking to get this Auth token from DialogsClass.cs to my Bot.Cs class file and use it to make Graph calls.

I have tried to save token as string in local file within my dialog class and then read it back in main bot class but this solution does not seems as a right way of doing it.

AuthDialog.cs in Waterfall step:

```
var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
```

Expected result. Transfer this token from Dialog class to MainBot.cs class and use as string to make Graph calls.

Comment: Hi! Can you post more then just one line of code? You said you've tried some things; can you post your attempts? You're probably on the right track, but we need to see it to help.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using one waterfall step to get token with OAuthPrompt and then another step to call a different class (in which you do graph api calls)?
Why can't you just pass the token to the down stream class?

If there are other steps in the middle, there are multiple ways to resolve it:

- Use [WaterfallStepContext Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/waterfallstepcontext?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#values)
- Save to [your own UserState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft suggests not to store token in the system but make a call to oAuth prompt 
`return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);` 
and get latest token whenever you have to call Graph API. Once you receive the token in `var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;`
 you can make a call to GraphClient class which will create the Graph API client using the token in Authorization attribute.

```
var client = new GraphClientHelper(tokenResponse.Token);
```

Graph Client implementation:

```
  public GraphClientHelper(string token)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(token));
        }
        _token = token;
    }
   private GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
    {
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                requestMessage =>
                {
                    // Append the access token to the request.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", _token);

                    // Get event times in the current time zone.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"" + TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id + "\"");

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }));
        return graphClient;
    }
```

Once graph client is created you can make a call to the intended graph api:

```
 await client.CreateMeeting(meetingDetails).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Please refer this sample code:
[Graph Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph)